# SSIS primary keys and Guids

Tags: ssis

I have a simple CSV file I'm importing. I have written a script task to accomplish it. My destination needs a primary key column so I added it in code.

But now I set out to do the same with a *Flat File Source*. However, I and have found [some](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/5463bf98-afa6-4577-8d81-f658799e1162/ssis-2005-derived-column-to-generate-auto-number) [sources](http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.de/2011/02/create-guid-column-in-ssis.html) that say the *Derived Column* cannot create an ID or a Guid column.

The only possible work arounds are either to write a TSQL statement on export to add a Guid or use a script component.

Is that really true? Can the *Derived Column* transformation realy not create a simple ID or Guid column? Is there any other way to do it without a script?

Answer (score 2):

You can set up the destination table that has an IDENTITY column as PK

You send all of your flat file columns into the table (ignoring the IDENTITY column).  The PK field will get incremented automatically during the insert.

Comment: Not to mention this will probably be faster, and you can get a similar result for GUID's

Answer (score 0):

No, `Derived Column` can't contain expressions which will increment/decrement values, and PK's need to be unique. Still, it's a very simple thing to achieve.

Create a variable `User::V_Counter` and place `Transformation Component` at the end of your DataFlow. Add a new PK column to the OutputBuffer. The code:

```
public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
{
   DTS.Variables["V_Counter"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(DTS.Variables["V_Counter"].Value)+1
   ResultBuffer.AddRow();
   ResultBuffer.myPK = DTS.Variables["V_Counter"].Value;
}
```

Map `myPK` as a destination input column. You can easily manipulate your PK format here - add string/date prefix and etc.

Comment: It'll do the trick, but I was looking for a way around the script. It looks like its the only way to do it.

Comment: The spirit is right but the implementation is wrong since this code doesn't actually work. The method for accessing Variables is only valid for Task Script and not Components. You can't access an SSIS Variable while the data flow is running. It's only in the pre/post execute events. You're also missing a semi-colon on the first line.

Comment: That's true, he'll have to change it into local script variable :)